# UITableViewCell's Data is being mixed up when using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm using GCD to load my UITableView data on the background thread, however doing so mixes up the data in my custom UITableViewCell. The titleLabel and imageView on the cell are fine, but the textLabel (the subtitle) is wrong on every cell. This doesn't happen when the data is loaded on the main thread, and the data doesn't come from multiple arrays, so I can only guess it's because of my use of GCD, which I am new to.

Firstly, I set up the NSOperationQueue like so...

```
- (void)setUpTableForAlbums
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
               {
                   [self setUpTableForAlbumsFD];
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                  {
                                      [albumTable reloadData];
                                  });
               });
}
```

The setUpTableForAlbumsFD selector is as so...

```
- (void)setUpTableForAlbumsFD
{
//    __block CLProgressIndeterminateView *clP = [[CLProgressIndeterminateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(325, tableScrollView.frame.size.height/2, 310, 20)];
//    [tableScrollView addSubview:clP];
//    [clP startAnimating];
type = @"Albums";
queryAlbums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
[queryAlbums setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

mainArrayAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
otherArrayAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
theOtherArrayAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *fullArray = [queryAlbums collections];
for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in fullArray)
{
    item = [collection representativeItem];
    NSString *albumName = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    NSString *albumArtist = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", albumName]];
    Album *album = [[Album alloc] init];
    album.albumTitle = albumName;
    album.albumArtwork = [UIImage imageImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (album.albumTitle.length > 4)
    {
        if ([album.albumTitle hasPrefix:@"The "])
        {
            album.albumOrderTitle = [album.albumTitle substringFromIndex:4];
        }
        else
        {
            album.albumOrderTitle = album.albumTitle;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        album.albumOrderTitle = album.albumTitle;
    }
    album.albumArtist = albumArtist;
    if (![mainArrayAlbum containsObject:album])
    {
        [mainArrayAlbum addObject:album];
    }

}
}
```

The Album custom class is just a container for the data.

The cellForRowAtIndex path method is as so...

```
MasterCellAlbum *albumCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!albumCell)
    {
        albumCell = [[MasterCellAlbum alloc] initWithStyle:nil reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    alphabet = [self alphabet:@"album" withIndex:YES];
    [albumCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    NSString *alpha = [alphabet objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.albumOrderTitle beginswith[c] %@", alpha];
    NSArray *predict = [mainArrayAlbum filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


    Album *album1 = [predict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    albumCell.titleLabel.text = album1.albumTitle;
    albumCell.textLabel.text = album1.albumArtist;
    albumCell.avatarImageView.image = album1.albumArtwork;

    longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(albumLittleMenu:)];
    [albumCell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    return albumCell;
```

Am I using GCD correctly, or is there another way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes.  There are lots of things that are, shall we say, *interesting* about this code.  Let's start with the first method:

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [NSInvocationOperation alloc];

operation = [operation initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setUpTableForAlbumsFD) object:nil];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^
{
  [albumTable reloadData];
}];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
operation = nil;
```

What I think you're tying to do is execute the `-setUpTableForAlbumsFD` method in the background, and then when it's done, reload the tableView.

First, the `completionBlock` doesn't execute on the main thread (which is where you MUST call `-reloadData` from).  The docs say:

> The exact execution context for your completion block is not guaranteed but is typically a secondary thread. Therefore, you should not use this block to do any work that requires a very specific execution context.

The simpler way to do this method would be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
  [self setUpTableForAlbumsFD];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [albumTable reloadData];
  }
});
```

---

Now for the `setUpTableForAlbumsFD` method...

```
- (void)setUpTableForAlbumsFD {
    type = @"Albums";
    queryAlbums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    [queryAlbums setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

    mainArrayAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *fullArray = [queryAlbums collections];
    for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in fullArray) {
        item = [collection representativeItem];
        NSString *albumName = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        NSString *albumArtist = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You should do these two lines of finding the `NSDocumentDirectory` outside of the `for` loop, for efficiency.

```
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", albumName]];

        UIImage *artwork = [UIImage imageImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

I'm assuming this is a `UIImage` category method?

```
        Album *album = [[Album alloc] init];
        album.albumTitle = albumName;
        if (album.albumTitle.length > 4) {
            if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c", [album.albumTitle characterAtIndex:0], [album.albumTitle characterAtIndex:1], [album.albumTitle characterAtIndex:2], [album.albumTitle characterAtIndex:3]] isEqual: @"The "]) {
```

Yikes!  Just do: `if ([album.albumTitle hasPrefix:@"The "]) {`

```
                album.albumOrderTitle = [album.albumTitle substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, album.albumTitle.length-4)];
```

And here do: `album.albumOrderTitle = [album.albumTitle substringFromIndex:4];`

```
            } else {
                album.albumOrderTitle = album.albumTitle;
            }
        } else {
            album.albumOrderTitle = album.albumTitle;
```

When you see multiple lines that are doing the same thing like this, it's a sign you can pull it out and do it differently.  For example, you could *always* set the `album.albumOrderTitle` to the `albumTitle`, and then only do something different if the albumTitle length is more than 4 and it has a prefix of @"The ".

```
        }
        album.albumArtist = albumArtist;
        album.albumArtwork = artwork;
        if (![mainArrayAlbum containsObject:album]) {
            [mainArrayAlbum addObject:album];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is similarly convoluted:

```
MasterCellAlbum *albumCell = [[MasterCellAlbum alloc] init];
```

You should be using `UITableView`'s cell-reuse mechanism.

```
alphabet = [self alphabet:@"album" withIndex:YES];
[albumCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
NSString *alpha = [alphabet objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.albumOrderTitle beginswith[c] %@", alpha];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

NSArray *predict = [mainArrayAlbum filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Why are you re-filtering the `mainArrayAlbum` *every* time you need a cell?  It looks like you're always going to be grabbing the same `alphabet`, which means you're always going to be defining the same predicate, which means you're always going to be ending up with the same `predict` array.

```
Album *album1 = [predict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
albumCell.titleLabel.text = album1.albumTitle;
albumCell.textLabel.text = album1.albumArtist;
if (album1.albumArtwork) {
    albumCell.avatarImageView.image = album1.albumArtwork;
} else {
    albumCell.avatarImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"albumArtInvertedLight1.png"];
}

longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(albumLittleMenu:)];
[albumCell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
return albumCell;
```

---

So, there are some obvious places where your code can use some improvement.  Honestly, I think the answer to the problem you're having is because you're trying to reload the tableview on a background thread, which is a Bad Idea™.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to using GCD, and a lot of other things here. Thanks for answering! Useful to have my code analysed by someone who knows that they're talking about!

Comment: And I had no idea the hasPrefix method existed.

Comment: @Gizmoloon 75% of being a good Cocoa developer is knowing what things the frameworks do for you for free. Even I don't know them all...

Comment: Sorry, it turned out I hadn't actually been loading it on the background thread at all. I'd been calling the second method straight away, and now I'm still getting the issue. Even with all the suggestions made above sorted, it's still mixing up the Labels on the cell...

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. I was using the "item" iVar throughout the ViewController. I changed the name and it was fine. Sorry about that.